# Discord.py username with multiple words and content with multiple words related problem

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to send a messages through bot in discord. It works perfectly when I'm send message to users whose nicknames has no "spaces", like: John#1234  or Im_the_best_traveller#1234 etc. but when to users whose nicknames contains of multiple words, like: Trying hard#1234 etc program sees only first word of nickname.

```
@bot.command()
async def sender(user: discord.User, *,content:str):
    await user.send(content)
```

I've tried to

```
@bot.command()
async def sender(user: ,*, discord.User, content:str):
    await user.send(content)
```

but after message that I want to send counted by program as part of nickname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of text commands. Arguments are separated by space. When you use `*, param` you are signaling that all remaining arguments must be consumed by the last param. There is no way to have two parameters that consume a variable amount of arguments, after all your command would not be able to delimit them ([read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)).

To work around this situation, you have some alternatives:

- Quote multi-word usernames (example: `"Trying hard#1234"`);
- Use the user ID or mention, which needs only 1 argument;
- Request the message to be sent within the execution of the command (more complex);
- Convert your command to Slash Command, where there is no such limitation.